# Which layout should I use to get non-overlapping edges in igraph in python?

Tags: python, igraph, edges

I want to make a graph without overlapping edges. I am using python with the igraph libray. This is my code

```
import sys
import igraph
from igraph import *
import re

g = Graph([(1,2),(1,4),(1,7),(1,10),(1,12),(2,3),(2,4),(2,9),(3,4),(3,5),
(5,6)

layout = g.layout_reingold_tilford_circular()

plot(g, layout=layout)
```

And this is the result

[image]

but I want something like this

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CM8r7sYUwAAEDy6.png]

Any help about how I can do it in igraph? My graph is not a tree.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961913/which-layout-should-i-use-to-get-non-overlapping-edges-in-igraph

Comment: Not a duplicate! The other question is about trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layout_reingold_tilford` and `layout_reingold_tilford_circular` are tree layouts; they are meant for tree graphs. You are probably better off with `layout_kamada_kawai()` or `layout_fruchterman_reingold()`.

Comment: Hi !!! I tried with layout_kamada_kawai() and layout_fruchterman_reingold() but this was the result https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CNCgGiYUAAAhU-c.png and https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CNCgGa_UEAAVCvg.png Do you know what I can make to draw the graph without overlapping edges??? Thanks a lot

Comment: If these algorithms did not work, you have to implement a planar graph layout algorithm on your own as igraph provides no algorithms that guarantee a planar layout for a planar graph.

Answer (score 1):

Using the option hovermost when plotting may help you

```
layout = h.layout("fruchterman_reingold")
igraph.plot(h, '2.png', layout=layout, bbox=(1000, 1000), margin=120, hovermode='closest')
```

Comment: This was great and worked perfectly for me. The `hovermode` helped a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tried the hovermode but it's not within the igraph package. The only think helped a little bit is play with the size of the figure, or use tkplot for manual handling of the figure.