# R: Untangle graph plot

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph

I have the following graph plot with 131 vertices made by using `plot` with an object of the `igraph` class. My question is whether there is any way to present this in a cleaner way so that nodes at least don't overlap each other and edges are more visible.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you can try some suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961913/which-layout-should-i-use-to-get-non-overlapping-edges-in-igraph?

Comment: Another place that had a relevant answer is [https://stackoverflow.com/q/37378744/4752675](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37378744/4752675)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with these types of graphs, so I can't provide a specific answer. But this sounds like a good time to use the `jitter()` function which adds random noise between the data points, thus separating them out.

Comment: Thanks, but still, their distribution on the 2D axis is arbitrary so I don't think `jitter` wouldn't do. I've used `vertex.size=5`. This separates the vertices but still edges are too crowded, `edge.width=0.2` doesn't seem to work.